# What value is there in keeping multiples of the same mirage?

Tags: world-of-final-fantasy

I have been playing a while now and have tried my best to imprism every mirage I've found. However this has lead me to have multiple mirages which are transfigurations of existing mirages. Such as Chocochick and Black Chocochick.

Not quite understanding transfigurations, I have levelled them all individually. Today I discovered that actually Black Chocochick is a transfig of Chocochick. This means that I can change my existing Chocochick into a Black Chocochick as and when I want, and keep all it's existing abilities.

I have similar situation with Floating Eye, Arhiman and Blood Eye. These are all transfigs of the same mirage, but now I have three levelled versions of the same mirage, all able to transfig between these forms.

The obvious bonus is if I want to use the same mirage in both Lann and Reynn's stacks, I can, because I have multiple copies. However, is there any value to having multiple copies? My Prism Case only stores 150 prisms, so there must be a limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than what you've already mentioned (being able to use the same Mirage in both stacks simultaneously), having multiples of the same Mirage can be beneficial in a few ways:

- If that Mirage has a Mirajewel on its board, you could get multiples of the same Mirajewel by levelling up your duplicates.
- Acquiring *more* duplicate Mirages (if you consider this beneficial...). Each instance of the Mirage you level up can produce a new Prism for that same type.
- Online trading via the Coliseum. Trade your duplicate Mirage away for a different one.

Also, worth noting: The Prism Case seems to expand as you progress through the game. Not sure what triggers this exactly, but I know mine currently has a max capacity of 180, as of Chapter 20 or so.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Jason Costabile's answer (on an old question)

Towards the end of the game (in Nightmare mode especially) one of the biggest advantages of multiple similar mirages is using XL variants against bosses.
The XL Behemoth (Behemonster) can do ~100K damage if you let its health burn down and use Revenge Blast - but can only be used once per fight (whether running out of MP or HP).

By having multiple of the same XL mirage you can call them "repeatedly" - (with MP recovery between, stack up on ether!) - Allows you to take down the toughest of bosses with comparatively little stress. If you find a mirage that works for you, why stop at 1?

When taking on elemental monsters, having matching elements in your stacks can save you a lot of pain, which becomes much easier if you have multiple Ifrits, Ramuhs and Shivas (of whatever transfig)